# In android studio, R marks up in Red giving Error Message "cannot resolver symbol R"

Tags: android

I've cleaned the project and rebuild it too. But problem still persists. How to resolve this issue now . I heard that if XML has some errors then it also shows up in Red. But I'm unable to find to find any error in XML.

Comment: there is some error possibly in your resources files.Check your console for the same.

Comment: @AnirudhSharma I've checked the res folder. checking XML's too. Couldn't find the errors,

Comment: wont be able to tell anything without the exception or logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the compatibility of your Java version ?

1-  Go to Google Website for Android/ Tool  (developer.google.com/Tool/...)

2-  Check the required Java version from Google. Usually, Google offers the link to download the most suitable Java version.

3-  Download the Pointed JAVA VERSION.

// I met this case and solved it by the above steps. Hope this useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem several times.  The first fix you alluded to with any errors in your xml files.

If the xml files truly have no errors, then you likely aren't generating the R file.  You can check for this in your project by looking in the auto generated java files project>gen>packagename>R.java.

If the file isn't there it is likeliest that you are mistakenly importing .android.R.  This happens as an unintended import fix when copy and pasting code between projects (at least it does in eclipse).  If you remove all of the 
    import .android.R 
statements then re-build you should generate an R file again.

If neither of those two are the case, I have had to use a third fix for this before, it involves editing a file that is clearly labeled "DONT EDIT OR MODIFY" by the android folks.  So I don't recommend it.  But I went into the project.properties file and flipped library from false to true.  I only had to do this once, and haven't even seen the option to do it a second time.

Sorry for the lengthy and multi-lathed answer.  Hopefully one of the first two options works!

Answer (score 0):

1. Close Studio
2. Go to task manager, kill all processes called `Android Studio` and `Java`.
3. Restart Studio
4. Do a build clean
5. Rebuild

At this point, if it still doesn't work, try syncing `gradle` again.